# How do RDS Proxy credentials work?

Tags: amazon-rds, proxy, credentials

In AWS RDS, there exists an RDS Proxy managed service. The console requires supplying database credentials when setting up this proxy. Why is this?

That is, why doesn't the proxy simply pass through credentials from the clients? If the proxy really does internally need its own credentials, why can't it glean those from the RDS instance that it is configured and managed together with (or use IAM access in preference to a password that will need rotating)?